# 100% height and padding = overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a setup that looks like this:

```
<html><head><style>
table{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0 20px 20px 20px;
    min-height:540px;
    min-width:720px;
}
tr.head{
    height:35px;
    background:black;
}
td.left-bar{
    background-color:green;
    width:220px;
}
td.spacer{
    width:10px;
}
td.right-bar{
    background-color:blue;
}
div.sb-top{
    height:20px;
    background-color:red;
}
div.sb-bottom{
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    padding:10px;
}
</style></head><body>
<table>
    <tr class="head"><td colspan='3'></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left-bar"><div class="sb-top"></div><div class="sb-bottom"></div></td>
        <td class="spacer"></td><td class="right-bar"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

However, when I do this both the height and padding on sb_bottom cause it to overflow past the cell. I'm not so concerned about the right/left overflow, but I absolutely must fix the bottom overflow. How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: overflow may not have been the right word. that makes the undesired part of the sb-bottom div invisible, but it is still there and any content it contains also becomes invisible which is not what i want

Answer (score 2):

You could always put an inner wrap inside of sb_bottom and give that the padding. That way it won't overflow.

Answer (score 1):

How about moving the padding to the body instead of the table?

If that does not work, you can put the table in a div and give the div the appropriate margins instead of a padding.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of your height and width 100% requirements... it will spread on its own. also, your min-heights and widths may be playing factors here... you can get rid of those too

Comment: Tables will automatically grow with content, sure, but what if there is not that much content in there? You can't just remove the height or min-height statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a hack, but I added padding-bottom to the left-bar and it looks okay.

```
td.left-bar{
    background-color:green;
    width:220px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
```

I loaded up the sb-bottom div with text and it scrolled off the screen, but I wasn't sure if you wanted the height to be fixed or to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `box-sizing: border-box;` on `div.sb-bottom`.

This would make sure height:100% includes the padding as well in the parent content height. Otherwise, actual height or the div will be height of the parent + padding which will always go beyond the parent content height.